# Qt-creator error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'xxx.h': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, qt-creator, cgal

I'm creating a qt project using QT-CREATOR and VS c++ compiler on windows OS,

**the .pro file:**

```
HEADERS = \
    mainwindow.h \
    myqglwidget.h \
    My_CGAL_Config.h \
    My_Vertex_base.h \
    My_Halfedge_base.h \
    My_Face_base.h \
    my_polyhedron.h
SOURCES = \
    Viewer.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp \
    myqglwidget.cpp \
    my_polyhedron.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += .
INCLUDEPATH += C:/dev/CGAL-4.9/auxiliary/gmp/include
INCLUDEPATH += C:/dev/CGAL-4.9/include
INCLUDEPATH += C:/local/boost_1_59_0
INCLUDEPATH += C:/dev/libQGLViewer-2.7.1/QGLViewer

LIBS += -LC:/dev/CGAL-4.9/lib
LIBS += -LC:/local/boost_1_59_0/lib
LIBS += -LC:/dev/libQGLViewer-2.7.1/QGLViewer -lQGLViewer2
```

[the errors:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzWzT.png)

'qglviewer.h','config.h' are  in  specified folders  (C:/dev/libQGLViewer-2.7.1/QGLViewer , C:\dev\CGAL-4.9\include\CGAL)  Respectively,
so I think that the problem in warning message "The build directory needs to be at the same level as the source directory."

**the compile output message :**

```
Error while building/deploying project dr_mine (kit: Desktop Qt 5.7.1 MSVC2013 64bit)
The kit Desktop Qt 5.7.1 MSVC2013 64bit has configuration issues which might be the root cause for this problem.
When executing step "Make"
```

I appreciate any help , thanks

Answer (score 0):

The warning 'The build directory needs to be at the same level as the source directory' means that your build directory should found near the source eg.:

```
c:\rootDir\src

c:\rootDir\build
```

I guess your Qt-installation isn't correctly installed. In a first instance, I should take a look at:

https://forum.qt.io/topic/56437/how-to-fix-error-while-building-deploying-project/6

or google for

> Error while building/deploying project

to find similar post.